# Flurry analytics tool for ios

Tags: ios, flurry

How to see what data/parameter are being sent using Flurry once you press the home button. Also when exactly does this communicate with their server(is it like only when you press the home button , it will send the event to their portal ?)

Answer (score 0):

The first place to check in the Flurry portal for Event data in your testing sessions is the Event Logs. To go to this section, select your app in the Flurry portal and select “Events” from the left navigation menu, then click “Event Logs”. Session data hits this section first and subsequently populates in the associated charts in the portal.

Event Logs should update within minutes of your test session. You will see the timestamp of the session, the device it came from, and a list of all the Events (and associated parameters) triggered during the session.

For more information on Event Logs and Event reporting in the Flurry portal,

[click here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Overview/Lexicon/EventReporting)

Comment: Thanks For the Reply, I was just looking from client side (Application side) how we can see what data are being sent to their portal